# Logic apps - Read XML response from web service and store parsed data in a database

Tags: sql-server, xml, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to use Logic Apps to accomplish something I have done with Pentaho in the past. I would like to build a Logic App with a Recurrence trigger, which starts an HTTP step to post to a web service and receive an XML reply. I would like to parse that XML reply (known format) and store the result in an Azure SQL Server database.

I have successfully tested the HTTP step and received the reply XML. I have the destination table completed in the SQL database. What I do not know how to do with Logic Apps is parse the XML reply into something like a CSV format that I can pass to a SQL query to input a new table row.

I have looked through several tutorials and other threads, but the steps either assume a greater level of experience than I possess, or are very basic intros to Logic Apps.

I think it would be helpful to hear something like the following:

1. Is this considerably more challenging than I anticipate? I'm good with SQL, Pentaho, R and other tools, but am somewhat new to HTTP calls / responses, and have very little XML experience.
2. What Logic Flow connectors I should be considering, and are they part of the free offering, or some paid package?

Thanks in advance for any help getting started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its much simpler if you convert the XML into a JSON object as well after parsing. Both of this can be done by using the the [`xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#xml) and [`json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#json) functions.

Also, since you know the format of the XML, you will know the format of the converted JSON as well letting you use the [`Parse JSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action) action to get simple tokens to use in the rest of the Logic App.

You can then use these tokens directly in the SQL query .

Here is a Logic App that show cases this (without the SQL and HTTP steps)

[image: Logic App Designer View]

and its definition to be clear

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "CSV_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "random_data_csv",
                            "type": "String",
                            "value": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['data']?['name']},@{body('Parse_JSON')?['data']?['awesome']}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@json(xml(variables('random_data_xml')))",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "data": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "awesome": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "name": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "XML_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "XML_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "random_data_xml",
                            "type": "String",
                            "value": "<data>\n<name>Azure Logic Apps</name>\n<awesome>true</awesome>\n</data>"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this @PramodValavala-MSFT. I've made some progress thanks to your description. I'm currently stumped on the Parse JSON step, as I'm having trouble passing XML to the JSON function as a variable from the prior step. This is how I'm attempting to do so, though I've tried other combinations with <>, etc. - am I close: https://imgur.com/a/WbUQ6Os

Comment: Both the `json` and `xml` functions expect objects when trying to convert from one to the other. So you would have to do it as `json(xml('xml_from_http'))` instead. Basically, you are converting the xml string to an xml object of sorts which can in turn be converted to a json object.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being thick. I tried json(xml('xml_from_http')), rather than json('xml_from_http'). I get the error below when running the job. My hunch is I'm trying to use 'xml_from_http'  improperly.     "InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Parse_JSON' inputs at line '1' and column '2408': 'The template language function 'xml' parameter is not valid. The provided value cannot be converted to XML: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#xml for usage details.'." https://imgur.com/a/8HFhlic

Comment: It has to be `json(xml(variables('xml_from_http')))` actually. Missed that before. You are just using a string instead of the value from the variable, hence the error.